# form to json in specific output in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i have a form like:

```
<form>
    <div id="studentlist">
        <div class="studentRow">
            <input name="first" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
            <input name="last" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
        </div>
        <div class="studentRow">
            <input name="first" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
            <input name="last" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
        </div>
        <div class="studentRow">
            <input name="first" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
            <input name="last" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <input id="send" value="Submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

and i would like to get json in a format:

```
 {"students":[
    {"first":"John", "last":"Doe"}, 
    {"first":"Anna", "last":"Smith"},
    {"first":"Peter", "last":"Jones"},
]}
```

i tried to use [jquery.serializeJSON](https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON) and i call it with:

```
 $('#form').submit(function() {
        console.log( $('#form').serializeJSON() ) ;
        return false;
    });
```

but all i get is:

```
Object { first: "Peter", last: "Jones" }
```

Any hint how to configure this plugin?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried passing `$('#form').serializeJSON()` to `JSON.stringify()`?

Comment: in this way i get `"{"first":"","last":""}"`

Comment: I assume you're trying to get a JSON string, vs. an object. Was your form filled out or where there values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be my solution personally but I think it would be easier to do this with PHP...

First, format the HTML correctly:

```
<form>
    <div id="studentlist">
        <div class="studentRow">
            <input name="students[0][first]" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
            <input name="students[0][last]" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
        </div>
        <div class="studentRow">
            <input name="students[1][first]" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
            <input name="students[1][last]" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
        </div>
        <div class="studentRow">
            <input name="students[2][first]" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
            <input name="students[2][last]" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <input id="send" value="Submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Then this would be my Javascript to get the array format you're looking for:

```
var x = $("#studentlist").find('input:last').attr('name').match(/^students\[([\d]+)\]/)[1];
var ary = [];
var obj = {};
for(var i = 0; i<=x; i++){
ary.push({first: $("input[name='students["+i+"][first]']").val(), last: $("input[name='students["+i+"][last]']").val()});
}
obj = { students: ary };
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since You're already using `jquery`, this might be the solution one of the solution:

html:

```
<form id="form">
  <div id="studentlist">
      <div class="studentRow">
          <input name="first" type="text" placeholder="First Name" value="firstname1">
          <input name="last" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" value="lastname1">
      </div>
      <div class="studentRow">
          <input name="first" type="text" placeholder="First Name" value="firstname2">
          <input name="last" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" value="lastname1">
      </div>
      <div class="studentRow">
          <input name="first" type="text" placeholder="First Name" value="firstname3">
          <input name="last" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" value="lastname1">
      </div>
  </div>
  <input value="Submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

and jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) 
{
  $('#form').submit(function(event) 
  {
    var students = [];
    var studentsObject = {};
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.studentRow').each(function()
    {
      students.push
      (
        { 
          first:$(this).find("input[name='first']").val(),
          last: $(this).find("input[name='last']").val()
        }
      );
    });
    studentsObject = {"students":students};
    console.log(JSON.stringify(studentsObject));
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the plugin you referenced, but here's a solution similar to the ones already posted. I aimed to make the code more understandable, so I separated out the different tasks into their own functions.

```
// Call this function with $('form'), and it will return the desired JSON
function getStudentsJson($form){
    var students = {
        "students": getStudents($form)
    };
    return JSON.stringify(students);
}

function getStudents($form){
    // Extract a list of student objects from the form
    // Each student object has the form {first, last}
    var students = [];
    $form.find(".studentRow").each(function(){
        students.push(getStudent(this));
    });
    return students;
}

function getStudent(row){
    // Extract the student object from a row, in the form {first, last}
    return { 'first': getFirstName(row), 'last': getLastName(row) };
}

function getFirstName(row){
    // Extract the input "first" from the row
    return $(row).find("input[name=first]").val();
}

function getLastName(row){
    // Extract the input "last" from the row
    return $(row).find("input[name=last]").val();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple piece of code creates the required json.

```
var studentsArray = $('.studentRow').map(function(){
    var data = $(':input', this).serializeArray();
    var obj = {};
    obj[data[0].name] = data[0].value;
    obj[data[1].name] = data[1].value;
    return obj;
}).get();
var students = {students: studentsArray};
var json = JSON.stringify(students);
```